# How do I set the test output to console instead of html in gradle for specs2

Tags: gradle, specs2

I'm using specs2/scala for unit tests and using gradle to build.  By default the unit-test output goes to a html file.  I would like to have the output go directly to stdout (just like sbt).

Anyone know the magic incantation?

thanks
wing

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
test {
  //makes the standard streams (err and out) visible at console when running tests
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

But this logs stdout at the info level so you need to run gradle -i to see it (it seems this will be fixed in 1.1: http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1966)

Alternatively, you can add an event handler:

```
test {
  onOutput { descriptor, event ->
    logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should this be added? I tried directly in `build.gradle` but got `Gradle DSL method not found: test()`

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but more of a suggestion since I'm not using Gradle. Can you pass arguments to the test action and did you try passing the "console" argument?

Comment: I think there is a way to set the 'console' argument for the runner in gradle... but that is my question since googling didn't get me the answer :)